# Opening XamWebDialogWindow on button click in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How do I open a XamWebDialogWindowon button click in silverlight. I am using a MVVM model and capturing button click in Controller

Answer (score 0):

The control you talk about is from the Infragistics suite,
there's a really good link [here](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/Current/CLR3.5/?target=xamWebDialogWindow.html) for the detailed explanation of how the control is used,
but to answer your question

```
//From the View.cs
XamWebDialogWindow myDialogWindow = new XamWebDialogWindow();
this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(dialogWindow);
```

This cannot be done in the ViewModel and should not, i like to set the DataSource of the popup window to the current ViewModel so i only need to deal with one DataSource once the popup occurs

```
XamWebDialogWindow myDialogWindow = new XamWebDialogWindow();
myDialogWindow.DataSource = this.Resources["DataSource"];
//Where "DataSource" is the x:Name of the DataSource on your parent xaml
```

If you really want to popup the window from your ViewModel, for whatever reason, there are ways, yes you can